# Setting Field Within Class using Reflection

Tags: class, reflection, field

This should be easy but it's managed to confound me a few times. I'm trying to set a Value within a class using Reflection.

```
 public class EngineeringValueClass<T> { 
      public  T Value  { get { } set { } }
 }
```

Then in a calling class I have:

```
 public class MyClass { 
    EngineeringValueClass<double> Value1;
    EngineeringValueClass<double> Value2;
    // Along with many others. 
    public void SetValueByName(object FieldName,object FieldValue) {

      // Get the "Value" field of a generic EngineeringValueClass<double> 
      PropertyInfo MyValuePropRef =               
           typeof(EngineeringValueClass<double>).GetProperty("Value");
      // Get the field within this class I want to set. 
      FieldInfo MyNameFieldRef = typeof(MyClass).GetField(FieldName.ToString());

      MyValuePropRef.SetValue(MyNameFieldRef.GetValue, 
                            FieldValue, 
                            null);
   } 
}
```

My goal is to have

```
SetValueByName("Value1",2.3);
```

set Value1's "Value" using the set accessor. I presume my problem is that MyNameFieldRef.GetValue doesn't return an object reference but rather a "Value", but I'm not sure how to work around that. I don't want to pass "this" because that's not right either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured this out:

```
public void SetValueByName(object FieldName, object FieldValue) {
  Type t = typeof(MyClass);
  FieldInfo PrimaryField = t.GetField(FieldName.ToString());
  object ValueField = PrimaryField.GetValue(this); 
  // To get the type of Value
  MethodInfo  TypeValueField = ValueField.GetType().GetMethod("GetValueType");
  Type ValueType = (Type) TypeValueField.Invoke(ValueField, null);
  // I added a "GetValueType () { return typeof(T); } to EngineeringValueClass
  if (ValueType == typeof(Int16))
  {
       ((EngineeringValueClass<Int16>)ValueField).Value = Int16.Parse(FieldValue.ToString());
  }... 
}
```